# draggable pannel Issue with resizing size for top video fragment

Tags: android

I am resizing the height of the player during orientation change but application getting freeze no controls on the player is working .

here is my code

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                // updateViewToLandscape();
                //  if(!needToHideNavBar()){
                videoPlayerFragment.getPlayerImpl().root.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenHeight();
                //  draggablePanel.setTopFragmentResize(true);
                draggablePanel.setTopViewHeight(getScreenHeight());
                // draggablePanel.setBottomFragment(new Fragment);
                draggablePanel.initializeView();
//                    draggablePanel.isClickToMaximizeEnabled();
//                    draggablePanel.isClickToMaximizeEnabled();
              //  hookDraggableViewListener();

                // draggablePanel.getRootView().settou
             //   this.getWindow().setFlags(
                      //  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                      //  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                //  }
            } else {
                if (getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED) {
                }
                videoPlayerFragment.getPlayerImpl().root.getLayoutParams().height = 600;
                draggablePanel.setTopViewHeight(600);

                // draggablePanel.setBottomFragment(new Fragment);
                draggablePanel.initializeView();
//                    draggablePanel.isClickToMaximizeEnabled();
//                    draggablePanel.isClickToMaximizeEnabled();
                //hookDraggableViewListener();
                //  draggablePanel.setTopViewHeight(400);

                //updateViewToPortrait(true);
              //  this.getWindow().clearFlags(
                       // WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            }
```

Comment: Your code is confusing and incomplete  just add code which is relevant  remove the commented one .

Comment: draggablePanel.initializeView(); because of this line my appliaction touch is not working

Comment: video is running in both of the orientations but no controls are working and whole application touch is not working only backpress is working..

Comment: dnt see commented code see uncommented one i dnt have tym to remove .

Comment: i am trying to set top view height but no application touch is working